# Use Bootstrap with SSRS report

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reporting-services, twitter-bootstrap-3, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to use Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) with a SSRS report?  Can it be applied on a report-by-report or group-of-reports basis?

I did read [How to apply customized css to SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033208/how-to-apply-customized-css-to-ssrs-report), but was hoping for a report-specific approach.

** edit **

By way of comparison, each field in Crystal Reports has a `CSS Class Name` attribute.  Is there a similar property (I didn't see one) in SSRS?

The other challenge is embedding the `LINK` element in the report's header.

Comment: To have almost unlimited customization, you could write your own [rendering extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), but before read the MSDN warning: `Writing a custom rendering extension is difficult. A rendering extension must typically support all possible combinations of report elements and requires that you implement hundreds of classes, interfaces, methods, and properties`

Comment: That's right Sébastien Sevrin. I've had issues too while working with SSRS CSS. The possible number of report elements you may get running a report randomly is hard to imagine.