# SSRS Report Builder: Get rid of strange gray squares rendered under lines in Chrome?

Tags: sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I recently used the work around in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428017/ssrs-2008-r2-ssrs-2012-reportviewer-reports-in-safari-chrome-but-works-fine) to get my SSRS reports to render in Chrome.  However, now that my reports are working in Chrome, I'm noticing a strange rendering issue.

I use horizontal lines in my reports that I draw using the "line" feature in SSRS.  When I run the report in Chrome, there is a gray square that appears below each line which causes my report not to look so great.  I've attached a screenshot containing an example.

Does anybody know how to get the gray squares to go away?

[image]

Comment: Same problem occur in crystal report also.I also want to know the correct solution.But I think you should inspect element in browser fix the bug via css.Dodn't treat this bug as Report bug,treat it is html bug.

Answer (score 4):

I've identified a work around that is working for my purposes.  I replaced my lines with rectangles, and resized the rectangles to look like lines.  My report now looks great.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few solutions if you are familiar with CSS or have access to edit the \Styles folder within your SSRS Server.

a.) [Tiny boxes appear when rendering SSRS reports in HTML viewed from Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454067/tiny-boxes-appear-when-rendering-ssrs-reports-in-html-viewed-from-chrome)

b.) [How to apply customized css to SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033208/how-to-apply-customized-css-to-ssrs-report)

c.) [ReportViewer showing broken images in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498696/reportviewer-showing-broken-images-in-chrome)

After researching these solutions above, either of them will solve the issue and make those nasty empty boxes go away. ~ The most effective solution I found was editing the CSS inside the \Styles folder, because it then applies that fix server wide.